# Passing state from child to parent in React, but state of parent lags behind state of child

Tags: reactjs, input, event-handling, parent-child, lag

After trawling various websites including Stackoverflow, I finally figured out how to pass state from child to parent. I have to do it twice since my structure is:
`<NavButtons>` child
`<Nav>` parent
`<App>` grandparent

The idea is to turn a click event into a string in `<NavButtons>`, save that string to state, pass the state to `<Nav>` and then pass it along again to `<App>` which will use the string to update the view.
The problem is that although the child state updates immediately on click, the parent state only updates after another click, then the grandparent will only update after yet another click. This seems like very strange behaviour and I can't seem to find a solution anywhere. I feel it is probably due to my poor understanding of the order in which things are happening in the lifecycle methods.

**NavButtons** (child)

```js
class NavButtons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { active: "" };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(num) {
    const btnArr = ["overview", "movement", "distribution"];
    this.setState({ active: btnArr[num] });
    this.props.getState(this.state.active);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("child says " + this.state.active);
    return (
      <div className="button-container">
        <ul className="nav-buttons">
          <li className="overview" onClick={() => this.handleClick(0)}>
            Overview
          </li>
          <li className="movement" onClick={() => this.handleClick(1)}>
            Movement
          </li>
          <li className="distribution" onClick={() => this.handleClick(2)}>
            Distribution
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Nav** (parent)

```js
class Nav extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { navState: "" };
    this.passNavState = this.passNavState.bind(this);
  }

  passNavState(nav) {
    this.setState({ navState: nav });
    this.props.NavStateUpdate(this.state.navState);
  }


  render() {
    console.log("parent says "+this.state.navState)
    return (
      <div className="nav-container">
        <img src={Logo} alt="Tharsus logo" />
        <NavButtons getState={this.passNavState} />
        <DatePicker />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**App** (grandparent)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      appDate: moment().format("1995-12-25", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
      apiData: "",
      navState: ""
    };
    this.getNavState = this.getNavState.bind(this);
  }

  getNavState(nav) {
    this.setState({ navState: nav });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const requestData = axios({
      url: "https://tharsus-interview-api-v1.azurewebsites.net/data/2019-10-19",
      method: "get",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({ apiData: response });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("grandparent says " + this.state.navState);
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Nav NavStateUpdate={this.getNavState} />
        {this.state.navState === "movement" ? (
          <div className="chart-container">
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={[3.3176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Site Hours"
            />
            <MovementDataDisplay
              Data={[3.9176110809420893, 4.18238891905791]}
              Title="Moving Hours"
            />
          </div>
        ) : (
          " "
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that setState does not immediately take effect (see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)). Consider this code fragment of yours:

```
    this.setState({ active: btnArr[num] });
    this.props.getState(this.state.active);
```

After setState is called, the state may (and likely will) still have the value of the old state. It will only be updated later. Therefore, when you call `this.props.getState(this.state.active)`, you are passing the old value of the state.

You could do a quick hack that passes the correct value to both methods, like this:

```
    const value = btnArr[num]
    this.setState({ active: value });
    this.props.getState(value);
```

...and that would work, but it's not an elegant way of doing things in React. You are keeping track of the same value in the state of 3 different components, which is not necessary and can get hard to maintain.

If you need the child to use the same value as a parent, I suggest you refactor your code a little bit. Let `App` keep track of the `active` navigation element, then pass that value as a prop to the `Nav` element. From the `Nav` element, you can also pass the value of the prop to the child elements. Then, all three components are guaranteed to have the same value at all times, and your code will be prettier since you only keep that value in one state.

So you would have:

- An `App` component that keeps track of the `active` value, and passes it to `Nav`, along with a function, `setActive`, that can be used to change it
- A `Nav` component that passes on both of these props to its `NavButton` children
- `NavButton` child elements that use the `active` prop to determine if they are active, and call the `setActive` function whenever they are clicked.

Comment: In addition to the recommended actions above, as I totally agree with it, I would like to recommend to take a quick look on React Hooks, you will see a good way of concern separation, which can help you more in sharing states between components. 
 https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Comment: THANK YOU for your comprehensive and thoughtful response! <3

Comment: But how could `App` keep track of the state? The state stores which button has been clicked, but the click event has to occur in the child... I can't see a way around passing information up the chain... I guess I could get rid of `NavButtons` and instead nest it inside `Nav`, but that would still mean passing state from `Nav` to `App`.

Comment: Wait maybe I understand! I can pass up a value without using state at all right? It's the fact that I'm storing the value in state each time that's causing the problems! I hope this is right, I feel like I just had a brain wave haha

Comment: @erasebegin correct! You don't need to store it in the state of all 3 components. You can create a function in App that changes the app state, and then you can pass that function down to the child components. When a NavButton is clicked, it can call that function, which will change the state.